# Append a linked list to the end of another linked list in Python

Tags: python, linked-list

I'm having trouble appending a linked list to another on python.
I think the logic should be to point the head of one list to the tail of the other. My code is the following.

```
def append(listA, listB):
    if listA == None:
        return listB
    elif listB == None:
        return listA
    headA = listA
    headB = listB
    cA = headA
    cB = headB
    count = 0
    while cA is not None:
        count += 1
        cA = cA.next
    #Here I replace since cA is null, i set it equal to cB
    cA = push(cB, cB.data)
    return headA
```

My test code is:

```
ten = Node(10)
seven = push(ten,7)
six = push(seven,6)
five = push(six,5)
four = push(five,4)

# ten = Node(10)
eleven = Node(11)
three = push(eleven,3)
two = push(three,2)
one = push(two,1)


print_list(one)
print_list(four)
append(one,four)
print_list(one)
```

Comment: What's `push` and `Node` ? Are you simply looking for `newList=listA+listB`?

Comment: Sorry, Node is:                                                                                              class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None
and push is:                                                                                                             def push(head, data):
    n = Node(data)
    n.next = head
    return n.            # I think you cannot do + for linked lists.

Comment: The built-in 'list' class is a double-linked list, no need to roll your own!

Comment: @AlonsoGutiérrez add the last comment to the question so that it is readable please.

Comment: @EvertW The built-in `list` type isn't implemented as a linked list but as a dynamic array. At least in CPython. But the devs somewhat promise O(1) index access, so it's very unlikely a linked list in any usable Python implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Thansk for the comments. I suppose the objective of the problem was to create an append function to merge two linked lists. I think I just had a mistake by pointing to the wrong location. I modified my code as follows, and it works:
The Node class and push methods are:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

def push(head, data):
    n = Node(data)
    n.next = head
    return n

def append(listA, listB):
    if listA == None:
        return listB
    elif listB == None:
        return listA
    headA = listA
    headB = listB
    cA = headA
    cB = headB
    count = 0
    while cA.next is not None:
        count += 1
        cA = cA.next
    cA.next = push(cB.next, cB.data)
    return headA
```